# How to make Python-based Discord Bot to play different sounds randomly?

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm coding a Discord Bot with Python.
I want it to join a voice channel and then play different sounds randomly from a list.
It could just play a specific audio file like every 10 seconds.

Everything else is working fine, the bot connects to a channel etc. but I don't know how to make it to stay on the voice channel and say things randomly.

Now it looks like this:

```
arvaus = [ *list of my files here* ]

@client.command()
async def arvaa(ctx):
   if not ctx.author.voice:
      return await ctx.send(ctx.message.author.mention + 'You need to connect to a voice channel')
    
guild = ctx.guild
voice_client: discord.VoiceClient = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=guild)
audio_source =(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="F:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe", source=random.choice(arvaus)))
voice_client.play(audio_source, after=None)
```

So basically now it plays one audio file until I type a command again to trigger another one.

Answer (score 0):

```
    async def play(self, ctx, *, query):
        """Plays a file from the local filesystem"""

        source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(query))
        ctx.voice_client.play(source, after=lambda e: print(f'Player error: {e}') if e else None)

        await ctx.send(f'Now playing: {query}')
```

this is a code in one of the example [discord_bot_voice](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_voice.py) myaybe try to implement this in you code say that after the bot connect play random sound sound from file  that you have

ADDITIONAL: the bot will automaticly disconnect after a while if you dont platy any sound so maybe just have the bot play file that have no sound until random time

maybe

```
arvaus = [ *list of my files here* ]

@client.command()
async def arvaa(ctx):
if not ctx.author.voice:
    return await ctx.send(ctx.message.author.mention + 'You need to connect to a voice 
channel')

guild = ctx.guild
voice_client: discord.VoiceClient = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=guild)
for i in range(len(arvaus)):
    audio_source = (discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="F:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe", 
    source=random.choice(arvaus)))
    randomtime = random.randint(20,200)
    await asyncio.sleep(ransomint)
    voice_client.play(audio_source, after=None)
```